# Hint to prove that $\frac{f(x;\alpha)}{f(1-x;\alpha)}-\frac{f(x;\beta)}{f(1-x;\beta)}>0$

Tags: inequality

Suppose we have the function $f(x;\alpha)$ defined on $[0,1]$, $\alpha$ is a parameter of the function. The function $f(\cdot)$ is monotone and continuous over $(0,1)$; non-linear, and $f(0;\alpha)=0$; $f(1;\alpha)=1$. In addition, we have the function $f(x;\beta)$, which has the same functional form, but parameters are different $(\alpha\neq\beta)$. I have a trouble to show that exists some $\alpha, \beta,x$ that satisfies the following inequality:
$$\frac{f(x;\alpha)}{f(1-x;\alpha)}-\frac{f(x;\beta)}{f(1-x;\beta)}>0.$$
Please give me hint how to prove!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96917/discussion-on-question-by-sane-hint-to-prove-that-fracfx-alphaf1-x-alp).

Answer (score 1):

Our choice is $f(x;\,\alpha):=\frac{x^\alpha}{(x^\alpha+(1-x)^\alpha)^{1/\alpha}}$ so $\frac{f(x;\,\alpha)}{f(1-x;\,\alpha)}=\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^\alpha$. For any $x\in(\frac12,\,1)$, your condition is equivalent to $\alpha>\beta$; for $x\in(0,\,\frac12)$, to $\alpha<\beta$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the functional form that I provided above, is empirically estimated, therefore it can be changed. Therefore, I used general notation for the question introducing properties of the function.